# Why does Spark perform an unnecessary shuffle during a joinWith on a pre-partitioned dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This example has been tested with Spark 2.4.x. Let's consider 2 simple dataframes:

```
case class Event(user_id: String, v: String)
case class User(user_id: String, name: String)
val events = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(Event("u1", "u1.1"),Event("u1", "u1.2"),Event("u2", "u2.1")))
val users = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(User("u1", "name1"),User("u2", "name2"),User("u3", "name3")))
```

When there is a `groupBy` followed by a `joinWith` on the same column, Spark performs an unecessary shuffle:

```
events
  .groupBy("user_id").agg(collect_list(struct("v")).alias("values"))
  .joinWith(users, events("user_id") === users("user_id"), "full_outer")
  .show
```

When doing the same thing with a join, the extra shuffle disappears:

```
events
  .groupBy("user_id").agg(collect_list(struct("v")).alias("values"))
  .join(users, events("user_id") === users("user_id"), "full_outer")
  .show
```

Is it a known issue?
Is there a workaround to use `joinWith` without the extra shuffle?

## Appendix : here are the SQL plans

- with `joinWith`

[image]

- with `join`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug introduced by a bug fix in [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15441). The result was wrong for `outer joins`.
Hence the need to add a `Project` node (packing of the struct) before the `Join` node.

However, we end up with this kind of query plan:

```
Join FullOuter, (_1#122.user_id = _2#123.user_id)
:- Project [named_struct(user_id, user_id#4, values, values#115) AS _1#122]
:  +- Aggregate [user_id#4], [user_id#4, collect_list(struct(v, v#5), 0, 0) AS values#115]
:     +- LocalRelation [user_id#4, v#5]
+- LocalRelation [_2#123]
```

The `Project` node prevents catalyst from optimizing the extra shuffle.

However, with [this PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/19aaf0f784cb01dffe98b03a98c88466c9d2c974) the `Project` node has been removed for inner joins and so the extra shuffle.